# Css in a separate file doesn't apply to index.html

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and I tried to create my webpage with the html as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My webpage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> My web page </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the following css

```css
h1{
  color: red;
}
```

I tried adding a class to the h1 and styling it that way but in vain. If i do the css in `style` tags inside my html file it works but i want to have it in a `main.css` file

I want the h1 to have the color red, also I would want the css in a separate file, no the same one as my html so that it will be clean

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you did not link your css file to the index.html, try something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">.
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1> My web page </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

But try to replace `./main.css` with the actual path of your main.css reffer to [this](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/htmlcss-linking) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

In the `head` section you have to link the `html` file to your `css` file.

Place the following code within `<head>` tags:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="[the path to your CSS file]">
```

Answer (score 2):

It is usually this tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourfilename.css">
```

But I think the problem you might be facing is the path of your css. Where is your css file located if it is inside a folder like a style folder then you would do something like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/yourfilename.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the css in the HTML file